# Should I flag this kind of copy+paste answer?

Tags: discussion

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20464705/2497102) really don't make sense and I think I should flag this, but if I should flag this answer what is the right flag? User just copy+pasted code from questioners post, exactly same code.

Comment: My diff tool says the question code block and the answer code block are *exactly the same*. (Just for future reference.)

Comment: Also, I flagged for moderator attention: *This answer is merely a code block copied verbatim (and I mean verbatim) from the question.*

Comment: So why was it upvoted so much? Rethorical question *sigh*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best course of action is to write a custom flag and explain that the code is *exactly* the same as it appears in the question. A "not an answer" flag, while technically correct, would probably be dismissed because a moderator doesn't normally think "oh, maybe this code is exactly the same as the code in the question" when processing those, even though copying and pasting the code isn't really an attempt at answering the question.

Comment: IMO we should have an optional custom comment on not-an-answer flags.